# get user login info in ASP

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an ASP website, which requires users to log in. it's a website application which enables them to create and submit invoices for the work (writing), the invoice creating process needs the user login info in order to make the invoice. How do you get the info of the logged in user to use it in your ASP or C# code? please help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

httpContext.Current.User.identity
see documentation for full explanation 
 [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)